# The system doesn't allow me to input the first number but allows the second number to go through

Tags: python

```
class Bank_Account:
  def __init__(self, accountnumber, accountBalance):
    self.accountnumber = accountnumber
    self.__accountbalance = accountBalance
  
  def readaccountbalancenumbernstuff(self):
    print(f"\n{self.accountnumber} and the balance for the account ${self.__accountbalance}.")

  def getdaaccountbalance(self):
    return self.__accountbalance

  def setdaaccountbalance(self, accountbalance):
    self.__accountbalance = accountbalance

  def addorminusmoneyintoaccount(self):
    self.__accountbalance += userdeporwithinput



banklist = [Bank_Account(34, 0), Bank_Account(23, 0)]

while True:
 print("""
 Please select one of the following options:
 1 - List all accounts and balances
 2 - Add a new account
 3 - Deposit/Withdraw from an account
 4 - Exit
 """)
 optionselect = input("\nChoose a number: ")
 if optionselect == "4":
   quit()

 elif optionselect == "2":
   while True:
    try:
     accountBalance = 0
     accountnumber = int(input("\nWhats the account number you would like to use?: "))
     if len(banklist) == 0:
      banklist.append( Bank_Account(accountnumber, accountBalance) )
      print("\nalright your good added the number to the system. :D")
      break
     counter = 0
     for each in banklist:
      addcounter = counter + 1
     if accountnumber != banklist[counter].accountnumber:
      banklist.append( Bank_Account(accountnumber, accountBalance) )
      print("\nalright your good added the number to the system. :D")
      break
     if accountnumber == banklist[counter].accountnumber:
      print("\nSomeone already took that number please enter another one. ")
    except:
      print("\nPlease enter a valid number.")
```

when i try to test the code

```
 Please select one of the following options:
 1 - List all accounts and balances
 2 - Add a new account
 3 - Deposit/Withdraw from an account
 4 - Exit
 

Choose a number: 2

Whats the account number you would like to use?: 34

Someone already took that number please enter another one. 

Whats the account number you would like to use?: 23

alright your good added the number to the system. :D
```

It doesn't allow the 34 to be used again but it allows the 23. Does this have to do with the counter? It looks like it just reads the first object and ignores the rest. It also does this for my other part of the code but I feel if I solve this I can fix the other methods too. I would appreciate help please and thanks

Comment: Welcome! Please format your question and post your full code

Comment: This is obviously not the full code.  Please post the **full** code, and please explain what you mean by "the first number" and "the second number".  There is only **one** input statement here...

Comment: It's opinion, but a single space for indentation in Python seems like an _awful_ idea.

Comment: Is this format good?, This my first time posting so im a little new.

Comment: You're only checking the **first** item in `banklist`.  And since account number 23 is the **second** item, it passes the test.

Comment: The format is technically correct, but most people prefer four spaces for indenting.  One space is too easy to overlook.

Comment: How do i make it so it checks all the items before it does the rest of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is allowing to use number `23` again because you are only checking the first item in the `banklist` list, and `23` is the second item.

There are many different ways you can check for all of the items. For example you can create a list of all used `accountnumber`, and than check if the new number is in that list:

```
    elif optionselect == "2":
        while True:
            try:
                accountBalance = 0
                accountnumber = int(input("\nWhats the account number you would like to use?: "))
                if len(banklist) == 0:
                    banklist.append( Bank_Account(accountnumber, accountBalance) )
                    print("\nalright your good added the number to the system. :D")
                    break
                
                # create a list of all existing account numbers
                exist_numbers = [account.accountnumber for account in banklist]
                # check if the account number is already being used
                if accountnumber not in exist_numbers:
                    banklist.append(Bank_Account(accountnumber, accountBalance) )
                    print("\nalright your good added the number to the system. :D")
                    break
                else:
                    print("\nSomeone already took that number please enter another one. ")
            except:
                print("\nPlease enter a valid number.")
```

For more esthetic and readable code you might want to stick with python conventions [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) or [here](https://visualgit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/naming_convention.html).